# lift isomorphic in a sufficiently thick fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $P$ and $P'$ two polynomials in $k[[\pi]][t]$ for an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $A=k[[\pi]]$.
We consider $ X'=Spec (A[t]/(P'))$ and $X=Spec (A[t]/(P)$.

Let $d=val(\Delta(P))$ where $\Delta(P)$ is the discriminant of $P$.

If the reductions of $P$ and $P'$ are equal modulo $\pi^{2d+1}$, do we have that $X$ is isomorhic to $X'$?

More generally if we replace $k[[\pi]]$ by $R[[\pi]]$ for an artinian ring $R$ and we suppose
that $P=P' [\Delta(P)^{2}\pi]$ do we have the same result?

Comment: I fixed the question.